# Iphone dev ios not picking up 2x images in ray's application

Tags: iphone

I have downloaded ray wenderlich's code for apns application from this link

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2

now i converted that project of ray's to tab bar application project, now i am having a problem with tab bar image. i added x and 2x resolution images in my images folder of project, and doing this in view will appear

```
AppDelegate *delegate2 =(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

for(UIView *view in delegate2.tabBarControler.tabBar.subviews) {  
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {  
                [view removeFromSuperview];  
            }  
        }
        [delegate2.tabBarControler.tabBar insertSubview:[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"]] autorelease] atIndex:0];
```

the 2x resolution image which is home@2x.png, it is not being picked by ios 5 device (ipod 4) i know that the operating system (ios 5) automatically senses the 2x image and pick it, but in my case its not happening, rather its picking the x resolution image and there is a white line showing under tab bar, i am stuck here , please guide me thanx and regards Saad.

Comment: Have you added the @2x images to your project as well as to your "images folder"? Also, that isn't how you set the image in a tab bar item, you're navigating a private view hierarchy there. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets run through some basics to see where something may have gone wrong;

Put the following line in your code, just after that and see what it prints out;

```
NSLog(@"Image scale : %f",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"] scale]);
```

If it prints out 'Image scale : 2.000000', that means the @2x image has been correctly identified and loaded by the app.

Also;

- Delete both images, clean the project, add them and try rebuilding
- Make sure the case of home.png and home@2x.png match exactly
- If you're trying this on a simulator, Reset the simulator and try again.
- If you already have a previous build on your device, delete it and try again.

Comment: Well, this helped me figure out that it's not sensing my @2x images, but it didn't help me figure out how to resolve that. +1 for the help.